# Pokemon go can see map but no pokemon on first time

Tags: pokemon-go

I can't see any Pokémon, but I can see the map, and it won't let me tap the screen. There also aren't any Pokéstops nearby me.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate, it appears to be a difference issue.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate people.  Please offset the downvotes and upvote instead.

Comment: If you can't see anything on the map, it may be because you're in a region where Pokémon Go hasn't released officially yet.

Comment: @fcm Nope, I'm familiar with this issue as I noticed someone else I know with the issue and fixed it for them.

Comment: It's certainly a dupe.  Perhaps not of that one, but a dupe, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The game hasn't loaded properly, try restarting the app. But if this error is persistent, you could try reinstalling the game. Also make sure that you have a good internet connection, and GPS.

Answer (score 0):

My wife installed this game on her mother's phone and had the exact same issue and they couldn't figure it out.  I took a look at the phone and noticed GPS/location was turned off.  I turned it on and it started working.